# PHP bugtracker with tasks calendar (from date, to date etc.)

Tags: php, calendar, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

We are currently using flyspray as bugtracker but it has not many tasks functions, especially no calendar view of tasks (only deadline task with date to which task must be completed).

Is there any PHP bugtracker with calendar like Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mantisbt.org/ is a very good PHP bug tracker. It supports time tracking, but I don't know if this is enough to fit your needs.